# hitTestPoint not giving correct results

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

<strike>I have a movie clip on which I have added a MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT listener.</strike>

```
movieclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removeMovieClip);
```

Now the logic is to remove the movie clip on `MOUSE_OUT` and add it back to stage on `MouseOver` of another button. The intended functionality is like a slider showing some info

The `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` firing in this case is not functioning always as expected. When I move the mouse out of the moveclip **fast it fires**. If I moveout **very slowly** it does not fire and consequently the movieclip remains on the stage.

What could be the problem?
.

**Update:** I forgot to mention that I use **hitTestPoint** to test if the mouse is outside of the **MovieClip**. In most of the cases if I move the mouse slowly, `hitTestPoint` does not give the correct results(false) that it’s outside of the Movieclip and hence I cannot remove the object.

**Update 2:** Let me rephrase the question. I think I have messed up the explanation.
The Mouse events work correctly.

```
movieclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT
```

fires correctly and I am in the event handled method. Now when I try to ascertain whether I am out of this MovieClip is when the problem arises.

```
private function removeObj(eve:Event):void
{
    var e:MouseEvent = MouseEvent(eve);
    if (m_wishlistImage)
    {
        var InsideSlot:Boolean = eve.currentTarget.hitTestPoint(e.stageX, e.stageY);
        if(!InsideSlot){
```

While moving the mouse slowly out of the object `InsideSlot` remains true and hence the code flow does not go inside the `if` condition and consequently I am unable to remove the object.

While tracing `e.stageX` I see that it often shows coordinates which is not exactly where the mouse is when it moved out (shows a point inside the slot). This behaviour shows up most often when I slowly move out.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Try ROLL_OUT instead, it seems more robust to me.

Answer (score 4):

Check that your mouse position is in *stage* coordinates (NOT your child movieclip coordinates).

In other words make sure you are using `stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY` as opposed to implicitly using the local member variables inside the movieclip (which will give the mouse position relative to the movieclip.)

hitTestPoint *requires the point to be given as stage coordinates.*

Answer (score 1):

try listening to the `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` event, instead.

Comment: it MUST work. :) check if the problem is elsewhere, maybe you have more layers on the same space?

Answer (score 1):

Well this problem can be solved if you replace your code of MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT to Event.ENTER_FRAME event. You need to use it because mouse-Movements are not captured sometimes in Mouse-Event listeners also because swf frame-rate is normally too faster to track mouse movements so use Event.ENTER_FRAME.

And i have faced such kind of problem before. So add listener to stage like this

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,removeMovieClip)

Now before removing an object or movieClip from container , put checks also like

public function removeMovieClip(evt:Event):void

{

If(ParentClip.contains(ChildClip)) ParentClip.removeChild(ChildClip)..

}

Comment: ROLL_OVER and MOUSE_OVER has a little difference. When a Movie-Clip or Display-Object Contains two or more childes then moving the mouse among the children will trigger MOUSE_OVER event each time when mouse is moved among them. Whereas ROLL_OVER is called once each time when you point to Parent-Container or any of its children after focusing the mouse somewhere else. Moving mouse among childes of MainContainer or any Display-Object will not trigger ROLL_OVER event.

Answer (score 0):

If your MovieClip's mouseChildren property is not set to false, it is plausible that you are triggering the MOUSE_OUT event before you expect to depending on the contents of the MovieClip.